# Why does "cat {foo}" not output foo, but "cat {foo,bar}" does?

Tags: bash, cat, brace-expansion

I was trying to concatenate text files in sub-folders and tried:

```
cat ./{mainfolder1,mainfolder2,mainfolder3}/{subfolder1}/book.txt > out$var
```

However this did not return anything. So, tried adding a non existing 'subfolder2'

```
cat ./{mainfolder1,mainfolder2,mainfolder3}/{subfolder1,subfolder2}/book.txt > out$var
```

And this time it did work out, concatenating the files successfully.
Why does this happens?

Comment: Use `echo` instead of `cat` to see what command line you got.  (Or use `set -x` for debugging.)

Answer (score 22):

By definition, brace expansion in GNU Bash requires either a sequence expression or a series of comma-separated values:

> Patterns to be brace expanded take the form of an optional preamble, followed by either a series of comma-separated strings or a sequence expression between a pair of braces, followed by an optional postscript.

You can [read the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) for details.

#### A few simple samples:

```
echo {subfolder1}
{subfolder1}

echo {subfolder1,subfolder2}
subfolder1 subfolder2

echo subfolder{1}
subfolder{1}

echo subfolder{1..2}
subfolder1 subfolder2
```

Answer (score 21):

`{subfolder1}` evaluates to `{subfolder1}`, since there are no alternatives. Use `subfolder1` instead.

Comment: Note that it's different from in `csh` (where brace expansion comes from), `tcsh` or `fish`.

Answer (score 1):

Braces will only expand if they have coma separated strings, for e.g. {abc,def} or range, for e.g. {a..e} specified between them.

In your case you can just write subfolder1 without enclosing it in braces as there is no need for that

```
cat ./{mainfolder1,mainfolder2,mainfolder3}/subfolder1/book.txt > out$var
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `/path/{a,}/filename` expands to the _two_ strings `/path/a/filename` and  `/path//filename`, which may be unwanted.

Comment: thanks @Kusalananda for rectifying me, yes bash will provide a warning saing  "ambiguous redirect"

Comment: No, you get `ambiguous redirect`  if you try to redirect into a file given by an unquoted variable that has no value, e.g. `echo 'hello' >$idontexist`.

Comment: ...or if the filename in the redirection gets expanded to multiple words. Like `> *.txt` with multiple `.txt` files, or `> $file` if `$file` contains whitespace. But of course there's nothing ambiguous in giving `cat` multiple arguments