# Why in bash {{a,b}.{c,d}} expands to {a.c} {a.d} {b.c} {b.d}

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

In bash 
`echo {{a,b}.{c,d}}` 
expands to 
`{a.c} {a.d} {b.c} {b.d}` 
Though nothing is mentioned for ***brace expansion*** in bash manual for the type of input I have made

My question is why the output is not like this **a.c  a.d  b.c  b.d**

Comment: ... Because there are braces on the outside...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `bash`, the expansion of `{word}` is `{word}` when the word does not contain a range (`..`) or a comma.

In your case `word` happens to contain two brace expansions.  These are expanded left to right, so you get, first `{a.{c,d}} {b.{c,d}}`, and then `{a.c} {a.d} {b.c} {b.d}` which is the final result.

Note that the outside braces are not expanded since they do not contain a range or a comma.  You would get a similar result with `@{a,b}.{c,d}@`.

Had you tried `{{a,b},{c,d}}` you would have three expansions (the expansion is done in three steps, each expanding one set of braces).  First the outer one into `{a,b} {c,d}` and then the left into `a b {c,d}`, and finally `a b c d`, which is the final result.

See also: [Why does "cat {foo}" not output foo, but "cat {foo,bar}" does?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444754)

Comment: Thanks it's now clear to me that braces will only expand if they have coma separated strings or range specified between them. However for the expression {{a,b},{c,d}} the output will be only a b c d  in bash, as all the braces will expand. It can also be proved by adding a preamble and a postfix, for example {c{a,o}t,d{o,a}g}

Comment: @Neo_Returns I was confused by your comment and edit-suggestion, then I realized I said "three expansions".  I  have clarified this now I hope.